# How to add new field in Candidate in OrangeHRM

Tags: php, symfony, orangehrm

I have experience in core PHP, but not in Symfony. I'm using OrangeHRM for the first time and I've tried to add some fields in candidate form, but that is not showing up in the database. I follow [this article](https://techgehlotravi.blogspot.in/2016/05/add-new-form-field-in-orangehrm-new.html), but no success yet.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, provide some examples of your code and/or errors you are receiving.

Comment: Did not geting any error custom filled are showing and when I submit form it refesh the page and all form filled with  previous value I followed article i mantion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You done perfect.

But you need to add validation for all fields. Add following code in $validators array.

```
'source' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false)),
'location' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false)),
'salexpected' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false)),
```

after that your data is inserted in job_candidate table.

I hope you will get solution.